# External table is not in expected format SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I am importing `.xlsx` to SQL but whenever I am importing from a large `.xlsx` file it gives me error :

> "External Table is not in expected format"

and whenever I am deleting some rows it runs fine. I have changed the Run64bit runtime to False. Still issue persists.

I am using SQL 2008R2.

Also when I change it to `.xls` and build package in SSIS 2005 it works.

The connection string I am using is `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";`

Answer (score 2):

Since you state it works when saved as an .xls file I would guess you are using the wrong connection string/provider.

You would typically use

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\path\to\file.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;
```

for a .xls file but you should use

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source\\path\to\file.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;
```

The [Microsoft Jet OLE DB 4.0](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/) provider supports excel up to version 2003.

The [Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/) supports new versions of Excel, but also old versions by specifying the version in Extended Properties.

In SSIS this is (I believe) specified by choosing the excel version in the connection manager dialog

[image]

Answer (score -1):

After some time i found the system was missing drivers, so once i install it it was working fine

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on what drivers were missing?  As it stands, your answer is likely to be deleted as it provides no details that would help a future visitor.